# Ruby Net-SSH get on-login text and send data

Tags: ruby, ssh, io, scripting

when I run this command from my linux terminal:

```
 ssh -p 12643 sudoku@ringzer0team.com
```

and enter the password, dg43zz6R0E, I get this message:

```
Linux ld64webdmz 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.82-1 x86_64
Last login: Fri Sep 22 09:19:02 2017 from 39.188.121.75
RingZer0 Team Online CTF
The sudoku challenge

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 4 | 8 |   |   | 1 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 6 | 7 |   |   | 5 |   |   | 4 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | 4 | 8 | 6 | 7 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 4 |   |   |   | 1 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 3 | 5 | 2 |   |   |   | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | 9 |   |   | 6 |   | 1 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 2 |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 |   |   |   |   |   | 1 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+


Solve this sudoku in less than 10 seconds and you'll get the flag.
Submit all the sudoku table using this format from left to right 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1...

Solution:
```

Using Net-SSH from Ruby, how can I get that on-login message and send a response?
This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require'net/ssh';

Net::SSH.start('ringzer0team.com', 'sudoku', :password => 'dg43zz6R0E', :port => 12643) do|ssh|
    # read that on_login text, solve and send output
    p ssh.exec!(((1..9).to_a*9).join(',')+"\n"); # trying to send data
end
```

It does not terminate (does not get past the call to exec!).

I'm just asking about how to interact with the session (get and send data), not on how to solve the sudoku.

Comment: What are you asking for here? Do you just need help interacting with the ssh session? Or do you need help parsing the puzzle and producing an answer?

Comment: I need help interacting with the ssh session (reading on-login data and sending the result)